# How can I get a df that is exactly like the .txt imput? (file has " " separator)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a TXT file that looks like this:

```
DBSH
(NFr) O (NTo) Nc C (Vmn (Vmx Bctrl (Qini) T A (Extr
 121             D 0950 1050   121   -10. C         
(G  O E (U) UOp (Sht ) M
 1        2   2    -5. S
 2        1   0   -10. S
FBAN
(NFr) O (NTo) Nc C (Vmn (Vmx Bctrl (Qini) T A (Extr
 125             D 0950 1050   125    3.1 C         
(G  O E (U) UOp (Sht ) M
 1        3   1    3.1 S
 2        1   0    -5. S
FBAN
```

I want to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
DBSH  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN Nan    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
(NFr) O    (NTo) Nc  C   (Vmn   (Vmx Bctrl (Qini) T   A   (Extr
121   NaN  NaN   NaN D   0950   1050 121   -10.   C   NaN NaN       
(G    O    E     (U) UOp (Sht ) M    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1     NaN  NaN   2   2   -5.    S    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   1   0   -10.   S    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
FBAN  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN Nan    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
(NFr) O   (NTo)  Nc  C   (Vmn   (Vmx Bctrl (Qini) T   A   (Extr
125   NaN NaN    NaN D   0950   1050 125   3.1    C   NaN NaN    
(G    O   E     (U) UOp (Sht )  M    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1     NaN NaN   3   1   3.1     S    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
2     NaN NaN   1   0   -5.     S    NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
FBAN  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN Nan    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
99999 NaN  NaN   NaN NaN Nan    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
```

I've done:

```
data_file = _teste
data_file_delimiter = " "
largest_columns_count = 0
with open(data_file, 'r') as temp_f:
    lines = temp_f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        column_count = len(l.split(data_file_delimiter))+1
        largest_columns_count = column_count if largest_columns_count < column_count else largest_columns_count
column_names = [i for i in range(0, largest_columns_count - 1)]
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, header=None, delimiter=data_file_delimiter,
                  names=column_names, dtype=object)
```

and got an output that is not satisfying. I don't realy know what to do from this, what's an awnser for this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the "largest_colummn"(which should be largest row), go through each line and change the delimiter to a comma. Add as many comas until you get the number of correct columns for each line. I am  guessing the space delimiter could make things complicated. You can add Nan when adding comas or change the empty responses to NaN at a late point. and replace commas at the end if that is what you want

Comment: I realised that the file is organized by character space ratter than a delimiter. Each column name has the exact amount of characters needed to organize the table. I still don't know how I could code it, but it at least helps me see how I could.

Comment: Looking more into the problem, the file is actually many .fwf files. I just need to look into how to separate them

Comment: So it is  fwf file and not txt?
Try reading about this:

 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: It came to me as .txt, only after reading into it I realised it was a .fwf. 
for the task I had to do, later I realised that using with open(file, 'r+) was enough

Comment: Maybe try pandas.read_fwf('file.txt'), names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']). Once you separate them